# How to Receive Arguments from Telegram User through Telegram Bot in Afl Amibroker?

Tags: telegram-bot, amibroker

I found how to [send message in amibroker through telegram bot](https://gist.github.com/marketcalls/f42f1d0a684eee96a89a134bad1ef3d0), but I don't found anyone discussing how to receive arguments from user. Is it possible to receive Telegram User Argument using Amibroker Afl?

Answer (score 0):

For receiving argument from telegram you need the bot to handle, you can make argument matched with .APX or some Amibroker OLE.
usually bot programmed with python and waiting for some request and argument to execute depend what section to access that is chart or exploring section.